# How to include python and Scala files all together in jar file using sbt?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, sbt

Goal:

> Build a single jar with scala and python files and supply this jar to
> pyspark and be able to call both scala and python files. Main
> execution will be in python files which will use scala libraries
> internally using py4j.

How to include python files/package in jar file along with scala files using SBT ?

Project structure (open to change to whatever works)

```
parent_project
|
|-- child_project
    |
    |-- src
        |
        |-- main
            |
            |-- scala
                |
                |-- com.my_org.child_project
                    |
                    |-- s_file_1.scala
                    |-- s_file_2.scala
            |-- python
                |
                |-- foo
                    |
                    |-- p_file_1.py
                    |-- p_file_2.py
    |-- build.sbt                      -- for child project
|-- build.sbt                          -- for parent project
```

Sample build.sbt (for child project)

```
name := "child_project"
version := "1.0.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.1"
val sparkVersion = "2.4.4"

lazy val dependencies = new {}

libraryDependencies ++= Seq()
```

Sample build.sbt (for parent project)

```
lazy val child_project = project.in(file("parent_project/child_project"))
  .dependsOn(parent % "provided->provided;compile->compile;test->test;runtime->runtime")
  .settings(
    name := "child_project",
    organization := "com.my_org",
    unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += file("/parent_project/child_project/src/main/python"),
    includeFilter in (Compile, unmanagedSources) := "*.scala" || "*.java" || "*.py"
    assemblySettings
  )
```

SBT Version = 0.13.16

SBT command for building jar

```
"project child_project" assembly
```

Specific questions:

1. Is it possible to include package both python and scala code in a single jar ?
2. Is it possible to supply this jar to pyspark and access both python and scala files out of it ?
3. Any suggestion / workaround / better options for achieving the goal ?

Answer (score 0):

A solution that immediately comes to my mind would be to place the `.py` files under `main/resources` directory. That seems more like a hack, but could be what you want perhaps (esp. for python files).

A much better solution would be to define `main/python` as a source directory as described in [Add an additional source directory](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html#Add+an+additional+source+directory):

> sbt collects `sources` from `unmanagedSourceDirectories`, which by default consists of `scalaSource` and `javaSource`. Add a directory to `unmanagedSourceDirectories` in the appropriate configuration to add a source directory. For example, to add extra-src to be an additional directory containing main sources,
>
> ```
> Compile / unmanagedSourceDirectories += baseDirectory.value / "extra-src"
> ```

That would be the following in your `build.sbt`:

```
Compile / unmanagedSourceDirectories += baseDirectory.value / "python"
```

Comment: Tried this but does not work. I have updated the question to reflect this setting, (sbt for parent project). Even tried keeping python file in `scala` source, that too does not work. Also added SBT version (0.13.16) in question.

Comment: Retried a clean build, deleting target directory, refreshing sbt and restarting sbt shell. Now it seems to respect the setting but fails with compilation errors, obviously while building python files.  Is it possible to skip compilation of python files ?

Comment: Every time you change `build.sbt` you have to _restarting sbt shell._ Where are the python files?

Comment: Thanks ! The python files are in /parent_project/child_project/src/main/python directory.

Comment: Marked `parent_project/child_project/src/main/python` as a resource folder. SBT is acting weird mostly. Sometimes it puts the python files in jar, sometimes does not. Anyway, this is the approach I have taken. Mark the python package as addition resource using following in project definition in build.sbt (parent one)
`unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += file("/parent_project/child_project/src/main/python")`